# Why this text comparision fails?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, equals

I am trying to get the text in the `EditText` component named `textfield` and see if it equals "facebook". It does not work though and I can't for the life of me find out why. Also in the if statement `my` is supposed to be the ID for the picture.

```
public class Guess extends Activity {

    ImageView image;
    ImageView stat;
    Button okButton;
    EditText textfield;

    Integer my;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.guess);

        final Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        int pic = bundle.getInt("myimage");
        final int resid = bundle.getInt("resourceID");

        my = pic;

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageResource(pic);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        stat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        stat.setImageResource(R.drawable.incorrect);

        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                textfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                if("2130837510".equals(my.toString()) && "facebook".equals(textfield.getText()));
                {
                    stat.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a semi colon ; on the end of your if condition ?

Comment: oops! that actually solved it @Luke ! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semi colon on the end of your if statement

```
if(1 == 2);
{
    System.out.println("passed");
}
```

so the code below will execute anyway.

Answer (score 3):

textfield.getText() returns an Editable not a String. To make it work pass the actual String object using textfield.getText().toString().

Comment: with the .toString() addition the image 'correct' is shown no matter what text is entered :/

Comment: I just noticed you have a ";" at the end of if statement. That means you will always set the "correct" image. Remove the ; and it should work.